# TypeError: b is undefined in Firefox when update store content

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, store

I am trying to update some grid columns when I select an option from a combobox (that is in the first column of the same grid), I am getting this error on Firefox with Firebug:

> TypeError: b is undefined

By the way I'm using **Extjs 4.2**

This is my code

```
    onComboboxSelect: function(combo, records, eOpts) {

    var grid = this.getGrillaFE();
    var store = grid.getStore();

    if( grid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection() )
    {
        var row = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
        console.log(row);

        //I got the error here:
        row.set("IdEmpresa", records[0].data.Id);

       //row.set("Contacto", records[0].data.Contacto);

       //row.set("Celular", records[0].data.Celular);
   }
    });
```

So when I check the value of row... it is updated with the new id, but I'm getting that error. So, is it ok? Or am I forgetting something?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to trace your error. Start by including debug version of Ext instead of compressed one, then either put a conditional breakpoint on the line where the error is triggered, or activate "stop on error" option in your debugging tool. Then... Try to understand what's happening ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @rixo. I am so frustrated with this, i would appreciate any help. I am using Architect for develop, and i am trying to learn as soon as i can. So if any way maybe you could help me? I would appreciatte it. Regards

Comment: I doubt anybody will be able to help you without having access to your code for debug. Maybe with the full stack trace someone could guess, but then again, that would be quite a feat!

Comment: You were right. The problem was the autoupdate event when the store get updated. One more question if i can ask you, @rixo... Althought i can see my store was updated... what i must do to get the grid updated(i mean at screen)... i must launch manually an "reload" or "refresh" event?... Thank you XD

Comment: I encountered a similar error on Firefox and was working fine on chrome. The difference was that i did not have redux devtools installed on firefox. Hope it helps someone in future